# navgiator.notification.alert() on Android not working.. Phonegap 3.0

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a phonegap app that is working perfectly on iOS.. it has now come time to port it to android... I am using phonegap 3.0 so the CLI installs the plugin however it still does not work.

Here is my code for the page requiring the alert or in this case the confirm.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
            //setup page
alert('deviceRead');
}

 navigator.notification.confirm(
 'blah blah',  // message
  onConfirm,  // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
  'title',    // title
  'cancel','ok'    // buttonLabels
  );


  function onConfirm(button) {

  if(button == 2)
  {
    alert('button 2 pressed');
  }
   else
   {
   }                                       
}
```

Could someone please help me with what I should be checking in my files? I am very new an Android dev so it might be the .java file or the config.xml?

EDIT: I should add that there are no errors being thrown in the log etc... and there is an alert() on either side of the confirm that gets called... its just as if it passes over the code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution was infact with my config.xml...

I was using :

```
<feature name="Notification">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
</feature>
```

Which is what phone gap have on their install page.. but infact I needed to change the feature to:

```
<feature name="Notification">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
```

Comment: The PhoneGap documentation is more misleading than it is helpful. Have yet to find 1 correct/complete page. Thanks.

Comment: Though, I managed to get an alert by changing "navigator.notification.alert()" to just "alert()" in my code,I'm curious to know -why couldn't I find <feature> tag in config.xml inside app root or platforms/android/res/xml folder. I tried to use "navigator.notification.alert()" after adding <feature> tag inside those xml files.I even tried [thisway]( http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert).But no luckk.I'm new to phonegap.Am I missing something.(I am using phone gap 3.5, CLI option, test device is 2.3.6 building with android api 19).

Comment: I got the answer. The plug-in was to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has errors try below code:

```
 function onDeviceReady() {

        navigator.notification.alert(
                'This is Alert',  
                onOK,  
                'Alert', 
                'ok'   
        );

        navigator.notification.confirm(
                'This is confirm',  // message
                onConfirm,  // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
                'button 2',    // title
                'cancel', 'ok'    // buttonLabels
        );


    }


    function onConfirm(button) {
        if (button == 2) {
            alert('button 2 pressed');
        } else {

        }
    }


    function onOK() {
        alert('OK pressed');
    }
```

Comment: I implemented this code but there is still nothing... I have put an alert() before and after the function and both of them fire without showing the confirm or alert in the above code...

Comment: Thanks for the help nick, found the solution in the config.xml... the way that phonegap recommends the import is wrong... silly. Anyway thanks again for the help.